# XML string to JavaScript array to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, xml-parsing

I have a JavaScript variable thats called XMLstring in the format:

```
<DataArray>
    <Node SERIAL="310835" DATE="07/07/2016" STATUS="Expired"/>
    <Node SERIAL="310836" DATE="08/07/2016" STATUS="Expired"/>
    <Node SERIAL="310837" DATE="10/07/2016" STATUS="Active"/>
</DataArray>
```

I want to get the  attributes into a JavaScript array so that I can then display them in a table with a row for each . The DataArray has varying quantities of Nodes. The desired table output is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>SERIAL<th/><th>DATE<th/><th>STATUS<th/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>310835</td><td>07/07/2016</td><td>Expired</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>310836</td><td>08/07/2016</td><td>Expired</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>310837</td><td>09/07/2016</td><td>Active</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To start with I can display the XMLstring in the console, so I can see that it does exist... but when I try to display it in the page all I get is: [object XMLDocument]
So far I have the following:

```
function(data) {
    var XMLstring = data;

    function parseXML(text) {
        var parser, xmlDoc;

        if (window.DOMParser) {
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
        } else {  // IE
            xmlDoc=  new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = "false";
            xmlDoc.loadXML(text); 
        }
        return xmlDoc;
    }
    var doc = parseXML(data);
    console.log(doc);
    document.getElementById("displayTable").innerHTML = doc;
}
```

And so then, how would I go about getting the Node attributes into an array and then displayed in a table? Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: Please read this: [http://www.w3schools.com/xml/met_element_getattribute.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/met_element_getattribute.asp)

Comment: in your code, 'doc' references a [Document](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document) object. Your console is not very helpful (consider using a better, recent browser for development), because the object is *not* just a dumb string, it's a whole DOM. You can access its elements in the usual ways, such as `doc.querySelector("Node[SERIAL=310836]")` or `doc.documentRoot.firstChild`…

Comment: That being said, transforming XML into HTML can be accomplished directly by applying an XSL transform instead of writing JavaScript code. Most browsers expose an [XSLTProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor) object to do that.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, your link lead me in the right direction. I can now getElementsByTagName and then getAttribute and have it display on the web page as in the example link you provided. I will post the code when I have arranged the data into a proper table.